# Templated sub-MenuItem not fitting in parent MenuItem's container

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm struggling with the horizontal fitting of contents when trying to display a UserControl in a ContextMenu, by templating one of its MenuItem:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MyUserControlMenuItemTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Grid>
        <MyUserControl/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>

<MenuItem x:Key="MyUserControlMenuItem" x:Shared="False" Header="My user control">
    <MenuItem Template="{StaticResource MyUserControlMenuItemTemplate}"/>
</MenuItem>

<ContextMenu x:Key="MyUserControlContextMenu" x:Shared="False">
    <ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <StaticResource ResourceKey="MyUserControlMenuItem"/>

            <!-- More stuff here -->
        </CompositeCollection>
    </ContextMenu.ItemsSource>
</ContextMenu>
```

This is mostly working, and I'm getting the context menu displayed under the desired circumstances and the UserControl accessible within it, as intended (a different question is whether this is a good design decision). The UserControl is just arranging some controls in a Grid.

The problem is that, depending on the position of the containing window and the actual screen resolution, sometimes the panel containing the templated menu item is not wide enough to hold it completely, and the user control is cut.

How could I get the UserControl to be dynamically resized in order to fit within the horizontal space available in the containing panel?

The UserControl XAML markup is as follows:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ListView Grid.Row="0"
                  Height="210"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ...}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding ...}"
                  SelectionMode="Single">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ...}" Header="First Name" Width="Auto"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ...}" Header="Last Name" Width="Auto"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ...}" Header="Address" Width="Auto"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>

        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid.Resources>
                <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4"/>
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="24"/>
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="24"/>
                </Style>

                <Style x:Key="ImageStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.35"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Grid.Resources>

            <Button  x:Name="FirstPageButton" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}">
                <Image Source="..." Style="{StaticResource ImageStyle}"/>
            </Button>

            <Button  x:Name="PreviousPageButton" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}">
                <Image Source="..." Style="{StaticResource ImageStyle}"/>
            </Button>

            <Button  x:Name="NextPageButton" Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}">
                <Image Source="..." Style="{StaticResource ImageStyle}"/>
            </Button>

            <Button  x:Name="LastPageButton" Grid.Column="3" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}">
                <Image Source="..." Style="{StaticResource ImageStyle}"/>
            </Button>

            <Button x:Name="OpenButton" Grid.Column="5" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}">
                <Image Source="..." Style="{StaticResource ImageStyle}"/>
            </Button>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I don't really think the issue is in the UserControl, though, but I may be well wrong.

Comment: Can you show the UserControl xaml?

Comment: @JamesHarcourt No problem, I've just included it.

Comment: I can't really see a problem ... I've implemented a similar structure here (different contents of course) - but everything sizes: http://s2.postimg.org/itc5gb0t5/image.png

Comment: Perhaps there is a `MaxWidth` set on the `MenuItem` by default? I'm fairly sure this is the `MenuItem` that is trimming your UserControl.

Comment: @MikeEason I've checked that and also explicitly given MaxWidth a high enough value, but it's still the same. The UserControl seems to always be rendered with the ActualWidth it needs to fit its contents, without attending to the size of its container (the default ItemsPanelTemplate for its parent MenuItem?), which is in turn sometimes clipped to prevent drawing beyond the screen limits.